# com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView not displaying in android studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, material-design, materialcardview

preview of design using xml is not showing com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView, but its shown when we install the app.

Comment: Try to 'Invalidate caches & restart'

Comment: No that is not working

Comment: Change your **app theme** from preview window to `Theme.MaterialComponents` or better and you'll get your result.

Comment: one more doubt, i have  a loader inside cardview and on clicking the cardview, the cardview inflates.Is there some solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theme on the layout preview windows needs to be or extend a Theme.MaterialComponents theme. Sometimes the theme in your layout preview doesn't reflect what's the actual theme of your app or view.

If you change the theme on your picker to a theme that is or Extends Theme.MaterialComponents the preview for the MaterialCardView should show.

The problem with this is that you just fixed for your machine and for a particular instance of Android Studio. Is very easy that config gets lost.

To avoid this and make it work on any machine you can place this on the root view of your layout file:

```
tools:theme="@style/YourMaterialComponentsTheme"
```

The `tools` namespace is just for preview purposes. If you really want this theme to take effect when you run the app on your device replace `tools` with `android`, but I wouldn't do this unless you know what you're doing in terms of themes and styles.

Answer (score 5):

make sure you are using this dependency in your build.gradle(Module:app)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

or any version of this dependency.

[see here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: i am using this one com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08

Comment: my suggestion is don't use alpha version. if you are using alpha then make sure you use correct theming

Answer (score 0):

**Method-1**
 Invalidate cache & Restart

**Method-2**
Make a backup of project 
delete .idea folder & .iml file and re-import project